# Tracking Clicks on a Link

Tags: html, click, event-tracking

I have my ad placement engine working on my website, but it only records impressions, and I have to infer clicks through a pretty convoluted redirect process. Is there a way to simply figure out when a certain link is being clicked?

Comment: which technologies are you using to serve the engine/website?

Comment: Just PHP for the ad placement engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Google Analytics enabled on your site, you can use that to track the click events. I blogged a while back about it here: http://enterpriseyness.com/2010/08/custom-event-tracking-with-google-analytics/

Comment: I'm using a different analytics software, but I want to tie in click event data with my current impressions readout.